# pallet-contracts and ink! version (v3.x.x & v4.0.0) compatibility

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts

ink! `v4.0.0` release is incoming. As mentioned in [`v4.0.0` pre-release page](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta), substrate pallet-contracts later than [this commit](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/265e3f12a2937fe4f71280b3652471627609d04f) (shows up in [polkadot-v0.9.32](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.32) branch for the first time) start to support ink! `v4.0.0`.

Are there any backward incompatibility issues with ink! v3.4.0 or lower? which contracts developers need to be aware of.
If yes, what exactly are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any backward incompatibility issues with ink! v3.4.0 or lower?

The `pallet-contracts` will continue supporting already deployed contracts and you will still be able to deploy ink! contracts lower than 4.0.

Since smart contracts are immutable execution environment (like `pallet-contracts` or EVM) will continue supporting already deployed ones.

If you are asking in terms of compatibility of your ink! v3.x code with 4.0: there are a couple of changes we made to the API. It's easy to migrate your contract code from 3.x to 4.0 though and we've written this migration guide for it: https://use.ink/faq/migrating-from-ink-3-to-4/.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the detailed explanation!